# Neutron-Antineutron creation/annihilation data

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, antimatter

What is the most precise data for neutron-antineutron production by one photon (hitting a target in the laboratory system)?

and/or

What is the most precise data for neutron-antineutron
annihilation to two photons? 
Is this data available online?

Comment: Bearing in mind that the neutron is a composite of quarks and gluons the neutron-antineutron reaction is going to be exceedingly messy. The probability that it will produce just two photons is vanishingly small. I'm sure Anna posted experimental data on proton-antiproton products in an answer (and it was messy) but I can't find the question ...

Comment: Aha! [This is the answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7063/what-actually-happens-when-an-anti-matter-projectile-collides-with-matter/7076#7076) I was thinking of.

Answer (score 1):

There is no process $ \gamma \to n $ at all, nor $ \gamma \to n \bar{n}$ with an on-shell photon. The first violated multiple quantum number conservation rules and the second conservation of four-momentum.

The two-photon process

$$ \gamma + \gamma \to n + \bar{n} \,,$$

has allowed quantum numbers but will be exceedingly rare.

---

It is worth noting that photons do no "annihilate" in the usual sense, and two photon processes imply multiple interaction vertexes.

Comment: I know but that was not my question. Sorry for the misleading formulation.